# Mesos java Application Monitoring

Tags: java, monitoring, mesos, marathon

I am running a java application on Mesos and Marathon. How do i monitor the heap stats of the java process? I tried jstat which complains "pid not found", but the process is running and i can check it by 'ps auwx'. Is this because the java process is running inside a cgroup? If that is the case how do we monitor mesos based applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option to monitor application is to publish it's metrics from itself. There are plenty of ways to add monitoring to your application starting from proprietarty such as [NewRelic](https://newrelic.com/) or [DataDog](https://www.datadoghq.com/) to opensource [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/).

If you need to get acces via JMX you can expose this port with following configuration:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=$PORT1 \
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=$MESOS_HOSTNAME
```

Above configuration assume you have two ports and second is dedicated for JMX